# C# Memory Access Violation during Textbox_TextChanged Event ( with database)

Tags: c#, mysql, access-violation, memory-access

I have a `textbox` in my C# Application. I have a `textbox_textchanged` function that checks if the user has changed its contents. If this event is triggered, it will get data from my database and place it as the `autocomplete source` of my `textbox`.

It works sometime, but most of the time it just put my application in break mode and then says `"Memory Access Violation"`

I am a newbie in C# and I have no idea why this is happening, I suspect that when typing fast, the trigger event is executed so fast that the mysql connection cannot keep up. Please Help me. :

Here is the function that handles the Textchanged event:

```
if (txtSearch.TextLength > 0)
        {

            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    using (var cmd = connect.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM search WHERE name LIKE @sname";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("sname", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%"));

                        using (MySqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                            AutoCompleteStringCollection collect = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                            while (read.Read())
                            {
                                collect.Add(read.GetString(0));
                            }
                            connect.Close();
                            read.Close();
                            read.Dispose();
                            txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collect;
                        }

                    }


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error(ex.Message, "Error");
            }




        }
    }
```

This is the error message:

Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

It should only update the `Autocomplete` collection of my textbox. Whats the Matter

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of:

```
connect.Close();
read.Close();
read.Dispose();
```

All that is done by the using() blocks. using() automaticlaly cleans up the resource you create in the brackets when the block exits. That's the whole point of this structure.

As you manually dispose "read", when the using block comes to tidy up, it's already been disposed, hence I believe the access violation.

Hope this helps,

Andy

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't you get an `ObjectDisposedException` in that case? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.objectdisposedexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Andy E, I tried commenting the said lines, the problem still persists. Also tried commenting ```read.Dispose()``` alone, but still no luck. Thank you for the suggestion sir.